# Is there any way to build an iOS app for Industrial Augmented Reality?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, object-recognition

I want to develop superimposition-based AR app (the device recognises a real world 3d object and overlays AR content) for manufacturing and/or automobile industry.

How to develop such kind of apps in iOS? Are there available apps using iOS or any other technology/platform?

For instance: if a car get detected then it will provide information about all parts of it as we rotate an object.

Comment: I'm sure you can do it with Apple's ARKit. Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects) about scanning and detecting 3d objects and Here is a [link] about horizontal plane which is kind of thing you might wanna take a look into. These docs will help you gain more understanding on how to do this. Here is a [tutorial](https://martinmitrevski.com/2018/09/13/driving-cars-with-arkit/) on how to build an AR app for car. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In **ARKit** framework you can use two approaches to accomplish industrial augmentation:

- [Image detection technique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/detecting_images_in_an_ar_experience). For this, you need to take a series of photos of an object from many different points of view. For me it's a less CPU/GPU intensive method.
- [3D object detection technique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects). It's CPU/GPU intensive method. It also requires from you more complex implementation.

Additionally, you may use **Vision** and **CoreML** frameworks for [Image Recognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml).

Hope this helps.